# "firebase serve --only functions" breaks after moving project folder

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-functions, firebase-tools

I've been working on a Firebase functions project, running the service locally for testing.

It was all working fine, but then I moved the source folder to a new location (into source control), and now it won't run, **because something, somewhere remembers the old location of the project**.

**So where the heck is Firebase 'remembering' the original location of the project/source?**

**And how do I fix it?**

---

### More info:

**Platform**: Windows 7
**Node**: v6.11.1 (as advised by: https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/writing)

Below is what the output looks like when I run 'firebase serve --only functions' and hit the service URL.

Ignore the lines with "Failed to emulate..." and "No HTTPS..." - That is normal.
The next "error:" line, and the rest is emitted when the URL is hit.

The important points are:

> a) The folder my project is in is shown on the first line (In standard Windows CMD prompt fashion)
>
> b) The "Cannot find module" error is looking in **A COMPLETELY DIFFERENT
> FOLDER**. In fact, it is looking where the project USED to be.

```
D:\_DEV\svn\FredSays\onGoogleAssistant\functions>firebase serve --only functions

=== Serving from 'D:\_DEV\svn\FredSays\onGoogleAssistant'...

i  functions: Preparing to emulate HTTPS functions. Support for other event types coming soon.
!  functions: Failed to emulate FredSays
i  functions: No HTTPS functions emulated. Support for other function types are coming soon.
error: module.js:471
    throw err;
    ^

Error: Cannot find module 'D:\_DEV\FredSays\actionssdk-say-number-nodejs-master\functions'
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (module.js:469:15)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:417:25)
    at Module.require (module.js:497:17)
    at require (internal/module.js:20:19)
    at process.on.e (D:\_TOOLS\nvm\v6.11.1\node_modules\firebase-tools\node_modules\@google-cloud\functions-emulator\src\supervisor\worker.js:64:28)
    at emitTwo (events.js:106:13)
    at process.emit (events.js:191:7)
    at process.nextTick (internal/child_process.js:758:12)
    at _combinedTickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:73:7)
    at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:104:9)
error: Function worker crashed with exit code: 1
```

I can't find anything in the project tree listing the old location.
I've tried all of the following:

```
npm cache clean
firebase init functions
firebase logout & firebase login
DEL /S /Q node_modules & npm install
npm uninstall -g firebase-tools & npm install -g firebase-tools
```

All of the above are no help.

Please help. My project is dead in the water right now.

Comment: you using nodejs version what ?

Comment: Nodejs version added. = v6.11.1, as advised by Google Cloud Functions doco.

Comment: Because of the error Failed to emulate     you try  [Run Functions Locally](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/local-emulator)

Comment: @aofdev - I'm not clear what you are saying. As shown above I am running locally, as per that link you supplied. Can you clarify what you are suggesting?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I came across your post whilst researching the same problem on my Ubuntu dev environment.  I copied some code from an NFS share to my home directory and can't for the life of me get it to run in the functions emulator - one of the issues was that the code was still being run on the NFS mounted path and not the local path where I was running VS Code.

The command you need to re-home the code after you move it is

```
$firebase use
Active Project: fbgo-9f73a

Project aliases for /home/user/firebase/chappy:

* default (site-ID)

Run firebase use --add to define a new project alias.
```

then start the emulator

```
$ firebase serve --only functions,hosting

=== Serving from '/home/user/firebase/chappy'...

i  functions: Preparing to emulate functions.
i  hosting: Serving hosting files from: public
✔  hosting: Local server: http://localhost:5000

✔  functions: app: http://localhost:5003/site-ID/us-central1/app
```

Unfortunately I don't have a 'before and after' on this to be 100% sure, please let me know if this fixes it for you.

Comment: Nice! Sorry for the delay, but 'firebase use' did indeed seem to fix the problem. Geeze, I'd tried just about every other command! Answer awarded.

Comment: Just to add some general info -- the place that firebase stores the currently "selected" project is in the file `~/.config/configstore/firebase-tools.json` under `activeProjects`. This is where your current project name is recorded when you run the `firebase use xxxxx` command.